# Handel response HTTP object in ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, pdf, save, response

I have a ajax code which is making a call to server in js, in response the server writes a pdf. can anybody tell me how to save this content.

Below is the content which i have been using:

```js
 var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }

var url ="some url";
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.responseType = "blob";

xmlhttp.onload = function () {
    onDownloaded(this);
};
xmlhttp.send();
```